# Local PostgreSQL instance returns empty on select inet_server_addr(),inet_client_addr();

Tags: postgresql

I was testing to see whether localhost would be returned (I have two separate PostgreSQL instances running locally) but the return values when typing `select inet_server_addr(),inet_client_addr();` are empty.

```sh
postgres=# select inet_server_addr(),inet_client_addr();
 inet_server_addr | inet_client_addr 
------------------+------------------
                  | 
(1 row)
```

What does empty here signify?

Comment: How do you connect to the server? Maybe unix-domain sockets are used and no "inet" at all?

Comment: @SebDieBln you are right, I get "via socket in "/tmp" at port "5433". Thanks for that comment! I assume there's a different command. My knowledge on this stuff is pretty limited, any references are appreciated!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I just posted an answer to let others know this question is answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does empty here signify?

It means you are not connecting via the network but locally via **unix-domain sockets**. According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) the returned values are `NULL` in this case:

> Returns the IP address on which the server accepted the current connection, or NULL if the current connection is via a Unix-domain socket.